# Could I use the pronoun "their" instead of "its" in this sentence?

Tags: usage, pronouns

> These changes have been made possible by use of the scientific method
>   to solve such problems as the causes of diseases and **its**
>   prevention.

Why writer used ***its*** instead of ***their*** in the sentence above?

Comment: Could you add the source?

Comment: The pronoun in the possessive “its” has an antecedent in the sentence. The antecedent is the word the pronoun refers to. The antecedent for “it’s is “scientific method” which is a compound noun and acts as a single noun. We may plug in the antecedent: These changes have been made possible by use of the *scientific method* to solve such problems as the causes of diseases and *scientific method’s prevention* (of diseases).

Answer (score 3):

Their is correct. The subject for this pronoun is "diseases". Verb-pronoun agreement can be a problem even for native speakers, and the writer made a mistake here.